# AngularJS ng-model not two-way binding properly as part of directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to make a simple Angular directive for a currency input. It should behave as a float in the model but it needs to display a  to the user. It also needs to force the display of 2 decimal places.

I made the following code for it:

```
//  Currency Input (Element Directive)
//  Simple text box that enforces 2 decimal place numeric input
//  Usage:
//      <currency
//          ng-model: string, angular model binding, optional
//      ></currency>
directives.directive('currency', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        template: '<span class="currency"><input type="text" ng-model="text" ng-transclude /></span>',
        scope: {
            ngModel: '=amount'
        },
        link: function($scope) {
            return function($scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
                $scope.$watch("text", function(newVal) {
                    $scope.amount = parseFloat(newVal);
                    console.log();
                    console.log("text changed, recalculating amount");
                    console.log("Successfully converted", newVal, "into", $scope.amount);
                });
                $scope.$watch("amount", function(newVal) {
                    $scope.text = newVal.toFixed(2);
                    console.log();
                    console.log("amount changed, recalculating text");
                    console.log("Successfully converted", newVal, "into", $scope.text);
                });
            }
        },

        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.text = "test";
            $scope.amount = 0;

            grabScope = function() { //Debug function to allow global access to this scope
                return $scope;
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Using this directive creates a textbox containing the word "test", but typing within that textbox fails to update $scope.text and, therefore, fails to kick off the watches and update the model.

I've been scratching my head for a while here, but I'm probably doing something really stupid. Any ideas?

Thanks,

YM

Comment: Can you create plunker or jsbin or jsfiddle for your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your link property is not implemented correctly.

It should be:

```
    link: function($scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            $scope.$watch("text", function(newVal) {
                $scope.amount = parseFloat(newVal);
                console.log();
                console.log("text changed, recalculating amount");
                console.log("Successfully converted", newVal, "into", $scope.amount);
            });
            $scope.$watch("amount", function(newVal) {
                $scope.text = newVal.toFixed(2);
                console.log();
                console.log("amount changed, recalculating text");
                console.log("Successfully converted", newVal, "into", $scope.store.text);
            });
        }
    },
```

Comment: Huh, you are correct. Weird, because I have another directive where returning a function from link works perfectly. Not hugely consistent. Thanks!